# expo: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a property name after '.'. no stack

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy realizando una aplicacióne en expo-cli y me apareció la siguiente pantalla. no dice donde esta el error y no porque se genera solo aparecer este mensaje en rojo: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a property name after '.'. no stack.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo por eso siempre lo tengo activo y conforme hago algo veo los resultados, por que luego sino pasa eso. Revisa lo ultimo que has codificado y ves quitando código hasta que funcione. Luego ves poniendo código hasta que vuelva a salir y encontrarás donde falla.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió revise y era un ponto al final del archivo es.json de i18n-js.